# Setting the className to a specific piece of state in mapped elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, array.prototype.map

I want to have several elements in my React app, each with their classNames determined by the value of a specific piece of state. These elements are mapped into `<p>` tags by an auxiliary function that ingests an array of objects.

Here is an example of what I want my end goal to look like,

```
<p className={this.state.notificationsClassName}>
    Notifications
</p>
```

Here is the map function I am using to generate these elements,

```
    generateTabs(array) {
        return Object.keys(array).map((key) => {
            return (
                <p className={??? something}>
                    {array[key].label}
                </p>
            );
        });
    }
```

Here is an example of the array I'm feeding to `generateTabs`,

```
const array = [
      {
        label: "Notifications",
        // I've tried both of these; 
        // className: {this.state.notificationsClassName},
        // className: "{this.state.notificationsClassName}",
      },
];
```

My problem comes from needing to store the data as a string in the object, but needing it to be interpreted as an object when mapped.

Thanks for looking through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your className in array config as a simple key string and resolve it from state.

```
const array = [
     {
       label: "Notifications",
       className: "notificationsClassName",
     },
 ];

generateTabs(array) {
    return Object.keys(array).map((key) => {
        return (
            <p className={this.state[array[key].className]}>
                {array[key].label}
            </p>
        );
    });
}
```

Suggestion : Your config i.e array seems to be an `array` but you are trying to loop them as `Object.keys` which is not required. You can simply use `array.map`

**Edit**: Using it with map:

```
generateTabs(array) {
    return array.map((obj) => {
        return (
            <p className={this.state[obj.className]}>
                {obj.label}
            </p>
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: The className works now, but I can't get the map to work without Object.keys. ```return array.map((key) => {``` returns undefined. Thanks btw

Comment: ok.. have added the code to use it with map. Please check if that works.